# How to integrate Facebook into WordPress registration/login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

Here's what we hope to accomplish:  a WordPress site that will allow users to register/login EITHER with Facebook OR WordPress and have the same access to posts/pages/content.  From all the research thus far, this doesn't seem trivial...

Here's our requirements:

---

### **User Registration**

**Facebook**

- New users can connect with Facebook by clicking a button and then granting the requested permissions to our Facebook App.  The permission-grant is a one-time event.
- They will have to log into Facebook if they aren’t already.
- When they connect for the first time a WordPress account will automatically be created for them.  This integrates Facebook and WordPress.
- This free plugin may be a good starting point to integrate the two systems - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/
- Here’s another one that only handles the WordPress account creation based on a Facebook session.  What it’s lacking is the ability to use the Facebook session to login after registration (it requries the WordPress username/password).   http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-registration-tool/

**WordPress**

- If the users doesn’t have a Facebook account or chooses not to connect through Facebook, they can manually create a WordPress account.
- Required fields are:  username, email, password

### User Login

**Facebook**

- If the user has already granted permissions to our Facebook App, they will be auto-logged-in if they have an active Facebook session and visit our website.
- Otherwise, the user will have to first log in to Facebook.

**WordPress**

- The user can choose to login with the username/password they created.

---

Any words of wisdom on how we can accomplish these requirements?

Comment: You got this working? Can you share what method you used?

Answer (score 16):

After several trials, the best plugin for this kind of job is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-connect/ It covers not only Facebook but also Twitter, WordPress.com and Google

Here you can find some details on installing it http://giannopoulos.net/2011/12/28/how-to-add-facebooktwitteretc-authentication-on-wordpress/

Comment: This plugin is not maintained anymore. The author himself suggests https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/ as a good alternative plugin to his own

Answer (score 1):

Facebook supports OpenID.

There is an OpenId plugin for Wordpress I know nothing about.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/openid/

Answer (score 1):

The best plugin which integrates Facebook (and also Twitter and Google Plus) is [WordPress Social Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login/).

Answer (score 1):

Definetly https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-facebook-login/ . Lightway and secure.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin I use on a BuddyPress site named [socialsnapin](http://socialsnapin.com) which I think should fulfill your criteria (although I haven't tested it with plain WordPress).

Comment: Seems like socialsnapin should work, but it doesn't.  I emailed their support to see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

try with keywords on wordpress.org :- facebook login. social login, facebook connect
There are more and awsome plugins for do this.
best i have tried:-

[FacebookAll](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebookall/) (with all facebook social plugins) By [sourceaddons](http://sourceaddons.com)